# Make a post request to sails with socket.io-client

Tags: sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to connect to my socket using socket.io-client
I'm able to make a get request using

```
this.socket.emit('get', {url: '/socket'}, (res) => console.log(res.body) );
```

But When i'm making a post request i don't know how to pass data into the request

```
this.socket.emit('post', {url: '/socket'},{message:"Hola"}, (res) => console.log(res.body) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `this.socket.post('<yourBaseURL>' + '/socket',{message: "Hola"});`
This is a method that worked for me, see if it does for you too. Make sure that you have the complete POST Url and not just the relative path like you provided in your example.

Comment: When I wake up later on, I will try it this way to see if this works for me, but here's the solution I came up with that works for me
`
       socket.emit('post', {url: '/socket', data:{message:"Sending Successfully"}}, (res) => console.log(res.body) );

Comment: Sure :) A practice might have multiple approaches. Use a standard practice for all of your methods, whichever suit you comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it working after messing around with it for a while. The solution was that in the options the key needed a data field to tell it to put it in the body of the Request.

```
socket.emit('post', {url: '/socket', data:{message:"Sending Successfully"}}, (res) => console.log(res.body) );
```

In the server now you can simply get the req and open req.body.message and the message will be right there